# Failed to load resources with vite pwa plugin in dev mode

Tags: vue.js, vite, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have a really simple vite app on which I try to use vite-pwa plugin in order to use it offline. It works well when building the app (`npm run build` and then `npm run preview`), but not in dev mode. When running `npm run dev`, no resources are loaded correctly:
[image]

My vite.config.ts looks like this:

```
...
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), VitePWA({
    registerType: 'autoUpdate',
    devOptions: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    manifest: {
      name: 'Your App Name',
      start_url: '.',
      display: 'standalone',
      icons: [
        {
          src: 'icon.svg',
          sizes: '192x192',
          type: 'image/svg+xml',
        }
      ],
    },
  })],
})
```

I've tried to add a custom cache using the workbox option in the vite.config.ts, but with no success.

```
workbox: {
  {
    urlPattern: ({ url }) => {
      let suffixArray = [".ts", ".vue", ".svg", ".css", ".webmanifest", ".js"];
      return suffixArray.some(suffix => url.pathname.endsWith(suffix));
    },
    handler: 'CacheFirst',
    options: {
      cacheName: 'static-cache',
      expiration: {
        maxEntries: 10,
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
      },
      cacheableResponse: {
        statuses: [0, 200]
      },
    }
  }
```

This `static-cache` seems to be caching some of the files, but not all, such as the main.ts file. And when I switch to offline mode, no resources are loaded.

So basically, I dont understand why the offline mode works well when the app is built, but not when in dev mode? I have read a lot on this subject, and it is still unclear to me what the underlying problem is. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I've just had the same issue, but found this...maybe there's an answer there ?

https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/guide/development#generatesw-strategy

In my case the error is occurring on the built app, not in Dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with this code is the parameter `maxEntries:10` that prevents more than 10 resources to be stored. Increasing this value solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your VitePWA({}), add these lines to cache all the required data:

```
  workbox: {
    globPatterns: ["**/*"],
  },
  includeAssets: ["**/*"],
```

Comment: I did try this solution but it didn't work. I really had to specify every different URL pattern possible to successfully store all the resources needed.